# Attempted Serialization Of ICollection even with IgnoreDataMember and JsonIgnore

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, code-first

I am having some issues avoiding serialization of certain ICollection properties in `Web Api`. It seems the common suggestion to avoiding serialization is to add `IgnoreDataMember` or `JsonIgnore`. I don't want to serialize the one-to-many and one-to-one properties.

I have the following model:

```
public class Player
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Friends { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<WordChallenge> IssuedChallenges { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<WordChallenge> ReceivedChallenges { get; set; }
}
```

However when I do a POST to the endpoint I'm getting the following exception:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

In this case it should only be attempting to serialize `PlayerId` and `Username`

Since it was requested, the following manages the dbContext:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Player>> GetFriends(Guid playerId)
{
    //Handles common exceptions and manages the dbcontext. In this case context is disposed off after the interaction is done.
    return await DbInteraction(
        async dbModel =>
        {
            var player = await GetPlayerById(playerId, dbModel);
            return player.Friends.ToList();
        });
}
```

Controller:

```
// GET: api/Friend/5
public async Task<ReturnObject<IEnumerable<Player>>> Get(Guid token, Guid id)
{
    var playerService = new PlayerService(base._wordModelFactory);
    var fields = await playerService.GetFriends(id);

    return ReturnData(fields);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that uses the `DbContext` object?

Comment: The context is being disposed off inside the service layer. I don't want it to persist outside of the service layer. That's why I don't want those properties to be serialized. I'll add the code in.

Comment: What about marking class with DataContract and mark all properties you _need_ with DataMember? So, explicitly set what you want to serialize, not what you do not want.

Comment: Can you show the `DbInteraction` method?

Comment: @Evk good suggestion. I'll take a look into DataContracts.

Comment: @YacoubMassad there isn't anything useful in that method for this particular case. It's just a wrapper around using(...)  to log exceptions and allow dbContext reuse in some cases. ` async Task<T> DbInteraction<T>(Func<IWordEntityModel, Task<T>> func, IWordEntityModel model = null)`

Comment: @Evk Thank you for your suggestion. That worked. If you'd like please add that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct to give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of marking members you don't want to be serialized with `IgnoreDataMember`, in your case (and in general) it's better to mark class with `DataContact` and mark members you *want* to be serialized with `DataMember`.

Still you might wonder why you observe such behavior with `IgnoreDataMember` and navigation properties. My guess would be - to support lazy loading when you access navigation property, EF might create dynamic proxy class for your POCO class. Note that your navigation properties are marked with "virtual". That is for EF to be able to override them in that dynamic proxy class and add lazy loading behavior. `IgnoreDataMember` attribute is not inherited, and so in that inherited proxy class navigation properties are not longer marked with it, and so serializer will try to include them.